# How to type hint a vue component method using Vue 2 with Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components `<Modal>` and `<App>` and I want to call a method of the Modal component. The code works when adding `@ts-ignore`, but TypeScript is complaining. I'm using Vue2 with Composition API.

Simplified example (I'm leaving out app initialization):

### Modal.vue

```
<template>
   <div ref="modalEl">I'm the modal<slot></slot></div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, onMounted, ref} from '@vue/composition-api';
import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';

export default defineComponent({
    setup(props) {
       const modalEl = ref<Element | string>('');
       let modal: Modal;

       onMounted(() => {
          modal = new Modal(modalEl.value);
       });

       const show = () => modal.show();

       return {
          modalEl,
          show,
       } 
    }
});
</script>
```

### App.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
       <Modal ref="modalSave">I'm modal content</Modal>
       <button @click="showModal">show modal</button>
   </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {ref,defineComponent} from '@vue/composition-api';
import Modal from 'Modal.vue';
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
      Modal
  },
  setup(props) {
      const modalSave = ref<InstanceType<typeof Modal> | null>(null);
      const showModal = () => modalSave.value?.show();

      return {
          modalSave,
          showModal
      }
  }
});

</script>
```

As mentioned, it works and I get even code completion in PhpStorm. But when I'm compiling I get the error:

> ERROR in App.vue.ts(115,24)
> TS2339: Property 'show' does not exist on type '{ readonly $el: Element; readonly $options: { data?: DefaultData | undefined; props?: string[] | { [x: string]: Prop | { type?: Prop | Prop[] | undefined; required?: boolean | undefined; default?: any; validator?: ((value: any) => boolean) | undefined; } | Prop<...>[]; } | undefined; ... 35 more ...'.

Does anyone know how to make TypeScript happy here without adding `ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `defineExpose` ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs)):

```js
<!-- MyModal.vue -->
<script setup lang="ts">
<template>
   <div ref="modalEl">I'm the modal<slot></slot></div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, onMounted, ref} from '@vue/composition-api';
import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';

export default defineComponent({
    setup(props) {
       const modalEl = ref<Element | string>('');

       onMounted(() => {
          modal = new Modal(modalEl.value);
       });

       const show = () => modal.show();

       defineExpose({ show }); 

       return {
          modalEl,
          show,
       } 
    }
});
</script>
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you defining `modal`? You assign to it in `onMounted`, but it's not declared anywhere. More importantly, what is its type before `onMounted`? Because that's what TypeScript will complain about: it doesn't have a `.show()` method when it's not a `Modal`.

Comment: @tao from what I understood OP only needs to expose the `show` method and not the entire `modal` definitions.

Comment: Unfortunately defineExpose is only available as of vue3 and the whole app is still written in vue2 (and can't be updated yet because of several other dependencies). In vue2 all returned vars are exposed.

Comment: sorry about the missing modal declaration, I'll add it to my question. You're right, it's missing - I was just writing it out of my head to keep the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was now able to solve it with (global) augmentation by putting this into a *.d.ts file. It's probably not the best solution, but as it's just temporary until the app is upgraded to vue3 it seems to be a simple solution without lots of rewriting:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        show: () => void
    }
}

export {}
```